# Redux Toolkit and Reactjs: change in a slice triggers re-render on components subscribed on other slices

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a react app bootstrapped with CRA where I implemented state management through reduxjs, using the @reduxjs/toolkit library. The state is currently composed of 4 different slices.

**My problem right now is that if I change even a single property of a slice, components that are subscribed to other slices, through the useSelector hook, do re-render, causing all sorts of weird behaviors that I didn't expect.**

Usually, the way I subscribe to a slice from components is the following:

```
const slice1 = useSelector(({ slice1 }: RootState) => slice1)
```

Where the RootState type represents all the slices that compose the store, combined with the combineReduce function like these:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
     slice1: SliceOneReducer,
     slice2: SliceTwoReducer,
     ...
})
```

I had the impression that using the deconstructing when selecting a slice form the state would avoid the component to re-render if the other slices change.

So my question is: **is this the correct behavior or am I doing things the wrong way?**

EDIT For the effects management I added the redux-observable middleware in the following way since I don't really like thunk:

```
const rootEpic: any = combineEpics(
    ...SliceOneEpics
)
```

And then when configuring the store:

```
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();

const store = configureStore({
    reducer: reducers,
     middleware: getDefaultMiddleware =>
        getDefaultMiddleware().prepend(
            epicMiddleware
        )
})

epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);
```

Could the middleware be messing things up? Maybe specifying the middleware in this way removes the default implementation of immer that @reduxjs/toolkit provides?

EDIT 2:
Following the comment of Mary, this is the reducer that basically causes all other slices to return a new object. The specific action, in this case, is the setShowQRCode. But the behavior is the same for any of the other actions. I'm updating the state directly because of immer doing its magic behind the curtains

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export interface UIState {
    themeLoaded?: boolean,
    layoutLoaded?: boolean,
    showQrCode?: boolean,
    showFloatingButton?: boolean,
    moduleLoading?: boolean
}

const uiSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'uistate',
    initialState: {} as UIState,
    reducers: {
        setUIState(state: UIState, { payload }: PayloadAction<UIState>) {
            Object.keys(payload).forEach(key => state[key] = payload[key])
        },
        setThemeLoaded(state: UIState, { payload }: PayloadAction<boolean>) {
            state.themeLoaded = payload
        },
        setLayoutLoaded(state: UIState, { payload }: PayloadAction<boolean>) {
            state.layoutLoaded = payload
        },
        setShowQRCode(state: UIState, { payload }: PayloadAction<boolean>) {
            state.showQrCode = payload
        }
    }
})

export const { setUIState, setThemeLoaded, setLayoutLoaded, setShowQRCode } = uiSlice.actions

export default uiSlice.reducer
```

Comment: The useSelector hook will trigger a re-render if its consecutive return values fail a strict equality check. I don't think it matters if you are destructuring the state object parameter. The problem could be that the reducer for your slice1 is returning a new slice1object every-time. Could you share your reducer code for that slice?

Comment: You saying "causing all sorts of weird behaviors that I didn't expect" without showing a single example of such behavior. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DennisVash of course, those behaviours are business-specific, but the root causing factor is a render of the component when it shouldn't, or at least that's what I expected

Comment: Can you show a specific minimal example of such "render of the component when it shouldn't"? You can use [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq)

Comment: @DennisVash I tried to reproduce the situation here https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-feather-5wj34. But it does behave correctly in this case, it might be bc the states are really simple. So the problem must be with the specific state objects that I use

Comment: Cool, so if you will be able to recreate, ask a new question, because it seems like a dead end.